# Includes the entire row of the changed cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I've tried looking this up but have had no luck hoping someone can help.
My spreadsheet has 3 columns: Customer, Location, Training Completed

When column 3 is changed to "Yes" I get an automated email, this part works great.
But, I would like to include the data from the row that was changed in the email. Is this possible?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue().toString(); 

  var recipients = "***@***.com" 
  
  if(cellvalue === 'Yes'){ 
    var subject = 'TRAINING COMPLETED';

    var body = "Training has been completed.." 

    GmailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);

   }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Show what you tried to get the result you are looking for and a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Your script was pretty close to getting what you need, but I modified it to get you the rest of the way. The below script will do the following:

1. Check to make sure that the user is inputting "Yes" into column 3 before executing
2. Collect the customer and location from the row containing the edited cell
3. email the given recipient with the customer, and location

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var editedRange = e.range;
  if (editedRange.getColumn() !== 3 || e.value !== 'Yes') return; // prevent the script from running when a "Yes" is not input into column 3
  var row = editedRange.getRow();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rowData = ss.getRange(row, 1, 1, 2).getValues()[0];
  var customer = rowData[0];
  var location = rowData[1];
  var recipients = "***@***.com" 
  var subject = 'TRAINING COMPLETED';
  var body = "Training has been completed by " + customer + " at " + location;
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
 }
```

#### Reference:

- [Event Objects: Edit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)